# QDeclarativeExtensionPlugin communicating with QML

Tags: c++, qt4, qml, meego

I am Writing a MeeGo Process viewer application, and I am having trouble getting the QML and the c++ communicating.

**Class Overview**

- List Item - A Q_OBJECT and used by the List Model
- List Model - This Class implements QAbstractListModel
- Plugin - This class implements from QDeclarativeExtensionPlugin and is used for creating a library that the QML can use.

> ```
>  #include <QtDeclarative>
>  #include <QtDeclarative/qdeclarative.h>
>
>  void ProcPlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri) 
>  {
>       qmlRegisterType<ListModel>(uri, 1, 0,"listmodel"); 
>  }    
>  Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(Proc, ProcPlugin)
> ```

**Project File (I Think This is the problem)**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = proc
QT += declarative
CONFIG += qt plugin

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
uri = com.int.components

# Input
SOURCES += \
    proc_plugin.cpp \
    listmodel.cpp \
    listitem.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    process.cpp \
    updatedaemon.cpp

HEADERS += \
    proc_plugin.h \
    listmodel.h \
    listitem.h \
    process.h \
    updatedaemon.h

OTHER_FILES = qmldir \
    qtc_packaging/meego.spec \
    proc.pro.user \
    Proc_view.svg

!equals(_PRO_FILE_PWD_, $$OUT_PWD) {
    copy_qmldir.target = $$OUT_PWD/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.depends = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/qmldir
    copy_qmldir.commands = $(COPY_FILE) \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.depends, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\" \"$$replace(copy_qmldir.target, /, $$QMAKE_DIR_SEP)\"
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += copy_qmldir
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$copy_qmldir.target
}

qmldir.files = qmldir
symbian {
    # ...
} else:unix {
    installPath = /usr/lib/qt4/imports/$$replace(uri, \\., /)
    qmldir.path = $$installPath
    target.path = $$installPath
    INSTALLS += target qmldir
}
```

**The QML**

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import "ColumnHelper.js" as ColumnHelper
import com.int.component 1.0

Rectangle {
    id:big_papa
    width: 680
    height: 200




    ListView {
        id: processView
        model: processModel
        property variant columnWidths: ColumnHelper.calcColumnWidths(model, processView)
        anchors.top: name.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: name.height
        anchors.fill: parent
        delegate:  ProcessItem { }

    }
}
```

**The error message**

main.qml:3:1: module "com.int.component" is not installed

import com.int.component 1.0

Thanks for reading this far!
Kyle

Answer (score 3):

I think this [video](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/elearning/watch/qt_quick_for_c_developers) could help you. It a nice tutorial showing how to integrate c++ and QML.

Normally you shouldn't have to mess with the *.pro* file but you have to add an `importPaths: [ ...]` directive in the *.qmlproject* file.

On the other hand it seems that you export you plugin with `Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(Proc, ProcPlugin)` but I don't see any `import Proc 1.0` in you QML file ...

Comment: The video was fantastic. Thanks!